# Howto send telnet escape sequence ^] with java org.apache.commons.net.telnet?

Tags: java, escaping, character, telnet

I created a telnet session to a serial converter in java using the org.apache.commons.net.telnet library.

Now I'm searching for how to send the escape character ^] to the serial converter before ending the telnet session with disconnect()

How can I send the escape character to the serial converter?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `static final char telnetEscape = 29;`  Is that what you needed to know?

Comment: So just writing the following code should be enough?
`static final char telnetEscape = 29;
telnetSend(telnetEscape);
this.tc.disconnect();`

but I can only send Strings with the telnetSend command

Comment: I don't know if `telnetSend` would work.  I wasn't sure what your question was, and my comment was guessing you perhaps didn't know how to create a `^]` character, and I was just pointing out that this is character 29 in the ASCII chart.  Whether sending it with `telnetSend` works, I don't know; I've never used this library.  To put that character in a string, use `"\035"` or `Character.toString(telnetEscape)`.

Comment: Hi ajb, using `"\035"` worked for me. Thanks a lot.